# Inputting Unicode mnemonics/diagraphs

Tags: gnome, unicode, unicode-entry

How do you input [unicode mnemonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Character_mnemonics) ([RFC 1345](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1345))? For example <kbd>-</kbd> then <kbd>+</kbd> gives ∓. This [cheatsheet](http://sheet.shiar.nl/digraphs) is nice reference.

Vim, Emacs, Screen and ZSH all have the ability to enter these, however I am unsure how to do it in other gui programs (e.g. firefox, chrome).

How can I enter these?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a universal way (but then again, I was unaware of Vim's digraph input so thanks for introducing me to it). So far the only thing I've found is [a Firefox extension to replicate Vim's digraph input mode](http://boldewyn.github.com/digraphs/docs.html).

Comment: Also, reading the Wikipedia article linked in the question lead me to finding the [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) website which allows you to find Unicode characters by drawing them. The number of times this would have come in handy is large. I like this question, I'm learning a lot of useful stuff from it.